# How to rebuild TensorFlow in Anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, binary

I keep getting this error while running my Keras script:

`2024-02-10 14:11:47.255446: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations. To enable the following instructions: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.`

I found the information in the Internet that I have to rebuild TensorFlow in order to get rid of this error and to speed my program. However, I need to use Anaconda. How can I rebuild TensorFlow from Anaconda?

According to instructions from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source , I installed everything needed to rebuild it but I am not sure where should I place TensorFlow repository. I don't know as well how commands should look like to match my problem. Where should I place Tensorflow files after rebuilding them to have them in Anaconda?

Edit:
I found solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-DM9GsKUv0

Comment: This is not an error, and there is no need to "solve it", its just an informative message.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding TensorFlow in Anaconda typically involves creating a new conda environment and installing TensorFlow from source. Here are general steps:
Create a new conda environment
:conda create --name
your_env_name python=3.x
conda activate
your_env_name
Install necessary dependencies:
conda install numpy bazel Clone TensorFlow repository:
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
cd tensorflow Configure TensorFlow build:./configure Follow the prompts to set the configuration options.Build TensorFlow:bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_packageBuild pip package:bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkgInstall the rebuilt TensorFlow:pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-version-cp3x-cp3xm-linux_x86_64.whlReplace your_env_name with your desired environment name and 3.x with your preferred Python version (e.g., 3.8). Also, ensure you have the necessary build tools installed on your system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, after building Tensorflow from scratch where should I place files to have them in my new anaconda enviornment?